# Any problem when I declare a class inside another class?

Tags: swift, class, object, oop

I am bit confused If any memory related issue happen when I declare classes  like below by using `Swift` programming language, The main purpose is to reduce real-time compile process. Because my system goes very slow If I declare class globally that is using in only one class.

```
  class Person {
    private var edu: Education? //network sync
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    private class Education { }
}
```

Here I used above class `person`

```
class SectionA {
    let amy: Person = .init(name: "Amy")
    let rachel: Person = .init(name: "Rachel")
    let sarah: Person = .init(name: "Sarah")
    let jack: Person = .init(name: "Jack")
}
```

What I am worried about is with class `Education`. Is the above class `Person` can take more process or memory than declaring class `Education` outside of `Person` like below?

```
class Person {
    private var edu: Education?
    let name: String
    
    init(name: String) {        
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Education { }
```

Thank you!

Comment: "The main purpose is to reduce real-time compile process. Because my system goes very slow If I declare class globally that is using in only one class." - I think you have the wrong idea here about how compilers work. It does not make any difference when you compile nested classes like this or if you just do them all globally.

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry I should mention `private class Education` (question updated).  Will it effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a class inside a class the way you have has exactly one impact: it changes the naming of the nested class. Instead of being called Module.Education, it's now Module.Person.Education.

That can be useful for organizing things. If Eduction can only apply to Person, maybe you want to cluster those concepts together and keep Education from polluting the top-level name-space. Other than that, it has no impact. It has no impact on visibility. It has no impact on access controls.

Given your comment that the "main purpose is to reduce real-time compile process," this has no important impact. It might slightly increase or decrease compile times for a particular code base, but the difference is unpredictable and likely small. Marking it private inside vs outside the class will have no impact at all (marking it private generally has very little impact, since the compiler is very good at marking things private when appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is to create a subclass which would inherit all the properties of your main class.

From my understanding it should look like this below:

```
class Person{
    

    var edu: Education? //network sync
    
    let name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
    
        self.name = name
    }
    
}

class Education: Person {


//insert info here

}
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstand. I just shown an Example. But the original program looks really different in iOS platform. Question updated. Please see, I am going to use the class `Education` inside `Person` only. So, Can I declare inside of class `Person` with private modifier instead of outside like you did?